# Read command line output

Tags: php, html, linux

Could any one help, How to read real time output from command terminal output in linux using php.

Below is code I tried but not working:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['pyinp'])){
$cmd = "ping 127.0.0.1";
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),   // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),   // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("pipe", "w")    // stderr is a pipe that the child will write to
);
flush();
$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, realpath('./'), array());
echo "<pre>";
if (is_resource($process)) {
    while ($s = fgets($pipes[1])) {
        print $s;
        flush();
    }
}
echo "</pre>";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="#" method="POST">
<input name = "pyinp" type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting submit button and when i press submit nothing is coming.

I am new to html and php. I just code in online.

Below code is working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="#" method="POST">
<input name = "pyinp" type="submit">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['pyinp'])){
$cmd = "ping 127.0.0.1";
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),   // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),   // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("pipe", "w")    // stderr is a pipe that the child will write to
);
echo "<pre>";
if( ($fp = popen("ls -l", "r")) ) {
    while( !feof($fp) ){
        echo fread($fp, 1024);
        flush(); // you have to flush buffer
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

But it does not work if i replace with ping 127.0.0.1

Thanks

Comment: Just a side note: Your HTML syntax of you form is wrong.

Comment: Do you have error or warning messages ? What is not working, please give more details.
Also, you don't have `<?php` at the beginning of your code.

Comment: @reporter and Benoit Zu, I have corrected code

Comment: the html is missing an opening <body> tag.

Comment: added but not working

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: You have an infinite loop before the HTML document closes.**

---

Let me rewrite your code, so that the ping output should go into the `<body>...</body>` container:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="#" method="POST">
<input name = "pyinp" type="submit">
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['pyinp'])){
$cmd = "ping 127.0.0.1";
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),   // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),   // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("pipe", "w")    // stderr is a pipe that the child will write to
);
flush();
$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, realpath('./'), array());
echo "<pre>";
if (is_resource($process)) {
    while ($s = fgets($pipes[1])) {
        print $s;
        flush();
    }
}
echo "</pre>";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, let's do a thought experiment. First time you `GET` the page, you see a form with a button. All is well. You click the button. The form gets `POST`ed back to itself. Then what happens?

First, the static HTML is output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="#" method="POST">
<input name = "pyinp" type="submit">
</form>
```

then the PHP engine activates:

```
<?php
```

Then PHP sees the button was pressed, and does a bunch of stuff to setup pipes (all of this is correct, BTW, you can check on the command line):

```
$cmd = "ping 127.0.0.1";
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),   // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),   // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("pipe", "w")    // stderr is a pipe that the child will write to
);
flush();
$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, realpath('./'), array());
echo "<pre>";
```

Then it checks that the connection is made (you really should add an `else` here):

```
if (is_resource($process)) {
```

Now what?

```
while ($s = fgets($pipes[1])) {
    print $s;
    flush();
}
```

That's right: a while loop that never ends! This spins and spins forever. Meanwhile, none of this gets executed:

```
?>

</body>
</html>
```

So the browser *never sees the body close*. So what, you ask? Well, the browser is under no obligation to display content until it has closed all tags.

"But, but, it does work sometimes!" you scream. Sure, sometimes it works. But this time it looks like the loading has just *stalled*, not just bad HTML. The browser doesn't know that you've got an infinite loop that will never end, so it's just waiting for you to close up your output.

[In general](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm):

> Web authors beware - unless you want to appear as an example in a Webkit error tolerance code - write well formed HTML.

If you want to see this work, then don't do an infinite loop:

```
$i = 0;
while ($s = fgets($pipes[1])) {
    print $s;
    flush();
    if (4 < $i++) { break; }
}
```

Or have Javascript load, calling back to a script that does the work.

Comment: It is still not working. after clicking submit noting is displaying added few more info in post

Comment: The reason the `ls` works is because its output ends after listing all files. `ping` never terminates, thus you have an infinite loop, the browser never sees the body close, and it jusy keeps waiting. Change your command to `ping -c 4 127.0.0.1` and you will see the output.

Comment: No luck i have used -c 4 option

Comment: What OS runs PHP? What browser and version?

Comment: Well, when I change it to `$cmd = "ping -c 4 127.0.0.1";` I get exactly the behavior I described: the page runs for a few seconds, then shows four pings. Bottom line: you cannot show output in real-time like you're used to on a command line using basic HTML. You need to switch to an asynchronous architecture.